# Trying to run a test to see how many children it takes to have one of each sex but the array is not working properly?

Tags: python, arrays, list, testing, probability

I am running some code for a class and I have no clue what to do, I submitted the assignment but it's not helpful if I don't know what to do in the end. Here is the code that I am running to try and track these tests. The idea is to see how many children it takes before you have at least 1 child of each sex. Then the program should be storing that to a list value as boysandgirls_stats[x]. The problem is that it won't store all tests. It only logs around 40 out of 100 or 200 out of 1000. I don't know where these other tests are being stored. stdarray is something we have to use from a book we are using. It tracks the tests similarly to how a list would in python but it wasn't explained well to me. Thank you!

```
import stdio
import random
import sys
import stdarray

numTrials = int(sys.argv[1])

boysandgirls_stats = stdarray.create1D(4, 0)
boys = 0
girls = 0
children = 0
totalChildren = 0


for x in range(numTrials):  # Simulation to determine sex
    childType = random.randint(0, 1)
    if childType == 0:
        boys += 1
        children += 1
        totalChildren += 1
    else:
        girls += 1
        children += 1
        totalChildren += 1
    for x in range(numTrials):  # Keeps track of amount of children needed
        if (boys >= 1) and (girls >= 1):
            if children <= 5:
                boysandgirls_stats[children - 2] += 1
                boys = 0
                girls = 0
                children = 0
            else:
                boysandgirls_stats[3] += 1
                boys = 0
                girls = 0
                children = 0
avgChildren = totalChildren / numTrials  # Calculation for average children
stdio.writeln('Avg # of children: ' + str(avgChildren))
for x in range(len(boysandgirls_stats)):
    stdio.writeln(str(x+2) + ' children ' + str(boysandgirls_stats[x]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
import random

## let's put the test inside a function:
def child_test():
  girl = False
  boy  = False
  total_children = 0
  while not (boy and girl): 
    total_children += 1
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
      boy = True
    else:
      girl = True
  return total_children


## now the statistics:
# get the number of trials from user command:
num_trials = int(sys.argv[1])

# for every number of children, log the associated number of tests:
total = 0
indexed_count = {}
for i in range(num_trials):
  num_children = child_test()
  if num_children not in indexed_count:
    indexed_count[num_children] = 0
  indexed_count[num_children] += 1
  total += num_children

# calculate and output the average:
average = total / num_trials
print(f'average is : {average}')

# show tries per number of children
sorted_indexed_count = sorted(indexed_count.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
for t in sorted_indexed_count:
  print(f'  {t[0]} children : {t[1]} tests')
```

Outputs :

```
$ python3 so.py 100000
average is : 3.00812
  2 children : 49702 tests
  3 children : 25238 tests
  4 children : 12401 tests
  5 children : 6314 tests
  6 children : 3159 tests
  7 children : 1528 tests
  8 children : 840 tests
  9 children : 410 tests
  10 children : 214 tests
  11 children : 99 tests
  12 children : 53 tests
  13 children : 18 tests
  14 children : 10 tests
  15 children : 6 tests
  16 children : 6 tests
  18 children : 1 tests
  17 children : 1 tests
```

Comment: I appreciate the simplification but I have to use an array to keep track of the number of children. The output should look something like this:
2 children: 4
3 children: 7
4 children: 13
5+ children: 2
I need to keep track of how many children it took to produce one of each sex. Thank you so far!

Comment: This still gives me an average which is great. I still need the individual amount of times that each total is received. I apologize this is difficult to explain. Say it takes 3 children to have one of each sex, then I need a list object to count up by 1. Same if it takes 5 or more children to get one of each sex. Once again I apologize, I am not very good at this.

Comment: Leaving this to close. In order to run a list, you must assign the childTest() variable to a certain index number:
if childTest() == 2:
    numberofchildren[0] += 1

and so on and so forth. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Alright I think I got it, for indexation you'd use a dictionary, you might want to take a look at this : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: I am not sure either. The code that you wrote worked and then from there I used iteration and if statements to track my list and print outputs. I used the original total_children / num_of_tests and it just gave me a float point result. Regardless it works for what it is intended. If my teacher wanted something different then it should have been explained better. The class doesn't help me much unfortunately.

Comment: Oh I removed my comment, but I got it. Average is 3 as should be. The median is 2.5.
Also edited the code with indexation counting.